# Calling Ajax from Datatable TableTools - Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am trying to call an `Ajax` page `'export_direct.php'` , which does the function of exporting some different data using `Php`. 
But though I am getting message as `'Ajax Complete'` from the below code, the call is not successful from the button, which works when called separately.

Any help ?

```
aButtons: [{
    sExtends: "ajax",
    sButtonText: "All",
    sAjaxUrl:"../ajax/export_direct.php",
    "fnClick": function( nButton, oConfig ) {
        var sData = this.fnGetTableData(oConfig);
        $.ajax({
            "url": oConfig.sAjaxUrl,
            "success": oConfig.fnAjaxComplete,
            "type": "POST",                              
            "error": function () {
                alert( "Error detected when sending table data to server" );
            }
        });
    }
}]
```

Comment: Are you actually checking what is being returned from the Ajax call? The php function could be showing an error message which you are not capturing.

Comment: Ajax call will export data as an excel file. This will work properly when I call this button separately from the same page. When I run this code, it returns success message, not the excel file

Comment: Here you forgot to send data with ajax; `sData` send like this `data:sData,`